# Browser Extension to import a CSS file on specific sites

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm looking for a browser extension that automatically loads a local CSS file when visiting a specific site online. For instance, let's say I navigated to www.google.com and wanted to utilize a CSS file on my local HD to overwrite / add styles. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Are you interested in finding an existing extension or developing your own ?

Comment: I'm looking for the exact same thing. I have a local CSS file I'm working on that I generate using SASS. It would save me a whole lotta time if there was some kind of plugin (or Tampermonkey userscript) that could just include the local generated file. I wouldn't have to copy and paste CSS-code (into Tampermonkey) every time I tweak something. Have you found a solution @Pathsofdesign?

Answer (score 3):

For Firefox there is [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/stylish/), which is kinda like Greasemonkey for CSS.

Comment: Stylish is also available for Chrome - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[This chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en)</kbd> called **stylebot**, does what your after. Once you select a stylesheet it will automatically be applied when you return to that url.

The icon in the top right of chrome also highlights green to notify you that stylebot is applying styles to the current page.

Comment: This is pretty close, however I'd like something that pulls from my local machine rather then having to upload it to the Stylebot server.

Comment: Both Stylebot and Stylish are good extensions. FWIW, I personally feel like managing styles in Stylish are slightly easier.